# objective c - app delegate - type casting

Tags: objective-c

I got the below code from a code sample. Can you let me know as per objective c, is this just type casting an appdelegate object which is already in session (or) creating a fresh uiapplication delegate object ?  Sorry, this is a basic question since am new to objective c but still I just want to make it clear before I proceed.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: It's just accessing and type-casting the pre-existing UIApplicationDelegate object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delegate` is just a getter. This code obtains a reference to the `UIApplication`'s `delegate` property... It does not create any new instances.

Comment: More informations here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

It's just accessing the `delegate` property of the singleton returned by `sharedApplication`. The typecast is necessary to suppress compiler warnings.